# jQuery focus cant focus on ajax loaded element

Tags: jquery, focus

i have made simple ajax call. e = element on which i click

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="order_notes">  
    <div class="order_note add">
      <div class="input"><input type="text" value="" /></div>    
      <div onclick="someFunction(e)">click it</div>
    </div>
    <div class="order_note">note</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This structure is loaded with ajax and i want after ajax to focus on input text again

```
function someFunction(e){
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/templates/design/inc/al_ajax.php",
        data: { action : 'add_note', order_number: o_num, commentar: com, user_id: user_id},
        beforeSend: function(data){       
        },
        success: function(data){
            e.closest(".row").find(".order_notes").html(data);
            console.log(e.closest(".row").find(".order_notes .add input").length);
            e.closest(".row").find(".order_notes .add input").focus(); 
        }   
    });
}
```

console.log returns 1 so the element exists where is the problem please. also data is correct and it correctly change everything in order_notes **including input so i need to focus on loaded input**

PS: the strucutre is more complicated i just simplified it for example

Comment: What defines `e`? Can you see the data?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your console. You're probably getting the following error message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined
```

For your `onclick` attribute, use `this` instead of `e`.

```
<div onclick="someFunction(this)">click it</div>
```

Also, in your `success` callback function, `e` will be a DOM object, not a jQuery object; therefore it will not be able to use `.closest()`.

You will need to convert `e` into a jQuery object, like this:

```
$(e)
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/y6zq55kq/

Comment: you are kidding me right? 
1. There is no error cause e is always defined cause the element e is loaded also
2. why (this) then jQuery(e) jQuery(this) does same and iti shorter
3. now you are probably right and this is probably problem

Answer (score 0):

so i the reason why i could not set focus was that .closest was nto working properly on given e element after ajax load so before i made an ajax call i put into r variable parent row

```
var r = e.closest(".row");
```

then i was looking for element inside of r

```
r.find(".order_notes .add input").focus();
```

instead of

```
e.closest(".row").find(".order_notes .add input").focus()
```